# date parameters to mvc action from jquery ajax are always null

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have the below ajax call code from jquery.

```
  $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: oAxn.ds,
            data: JSON.stringify(oAxn.p(graphsDrpDwn)),
            beforeSend: function () {
                $(".errorMsg").hide();
                YC.toggleLoadingImg(tabId, false);
            },
            success: function (graphData) {
                if (typeof oAxn.s === "function") {
                    if (graphData.reportData.ErrorMsg !== "Success") {
                        $(".errorMsg").show().html(graphData.reportData.ErrorMsg);
                        $("#tabs").hide();
                        YC.toggleLoadingImg(tabId, true);
                    } else {
                        //Inorder to avoid flicker, we hide in style sheet on page load.
                        $("#tabs").show();
                        $(".lblDrp").show();
                        $("#MainDiv").show();
                        YC.showRangeSel();
                        YC.toggleLoadingImg(tabId, true);
                        oAxn.s(graphData, grphOneID, grphTwoID);
                    }
                }
            },
            error: function (err) {
                YC.toggleLoadingImg(tabId, true);
            }
        });
```

The method that gets the parameters JSON.stringify(oAxn.p(graphsDrpDwn))  is:

```
getDealerParams: function (graphsDrpDwn) {
        /// <summary>We gather the parameters required for dealer tab</summary>
        /// <param name="graphsDrpDwn" type="string">Holds the dropdown list id</param>

        return {
            //We get these from hidden inputs, since they won't be available
            //  in the query string for framed in reports
            shopId: $(".txtShopId").val(),
            siteId: $("." + graphsDrpDwn).find(":selected").attr("data-field"),
            dealerId: $("." + graphsDrpDwn).find(":selected").val(),
            frmDate: $(".tsFrom").val(),
            toDate: $(".tsTo").val()
        };
    },
```

All parameters are getting values except frmDate, toDate.
I can see the values in client side but when passed to controller two are always null.
And it is only happening in my system, it is working fine in my colleagues machine.
can some body advise what could be wrong here?

Comment: Since the problems is with date fields and on certain machine(s) only, it could be a discrepency between the default settings for the date field and/or culture that is preventing the date from being parsed properly. Try using dates where both month and day are less than 13 and see if they work.

Comment: yes...its really working when both are less than 13. where can i change the settings to allow mm dd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the below attributes in aspx file for page directive worked for me.

UICulture="es" Culture="es-US"

Answer (score 0):

This is not the ideal solution but it worked for us on couple projects. In Global.asax we put the following code:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var newCulture = (CultureInfo)Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
        newCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";
        newCulture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator = "/";
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;
    }
```

Of course you need to change the date format to the one you need.